# Linking Qs to more Qs based on answers the user gives Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to link a question to another question so for example if the user inserts no, it will take you to another questions. It will keep going like this until you find a solution. It is like a troubleshooting program.
My question is, how can I link a question to another question?

```
answer1 = "yes"
answer2 = "no"
question = "did you drop your phone?"
print(question)
guess = input().lower()
name = input("Please enter your answer: ")
if guess == answer1:
    print("I will ask you new question")
if guess == answer2:
    print("Next question")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

I got the answer for the code but i want a simpler version of the code. For example the IDs code is a bit hard for me so can someone make a full code here with this code?

**CODE:**

```
These are all my solutions from solution2 to sol8. Sol8 means solution 8.   The code whithin the red comment hashtags are all the solutions except the print    function which is to start off the program.

print("Welcome to the troubleshooting program.Please answer 'yes' or 'no' to  all questions.")##
solution2 = "Please get a screen replaced."
solution1 = "Your device is still under warranty"#
solution = "Reset your phone"
sol0 = "Delete some apps, you need atleast 5 GB of memory to run your phone properly."
sol1 = "Take out everything from the phone(battery,SIM card etc.)and place  the phone in a bowl of rice.\nLeave it there for about 24 hours to let the rice   absorb the water"#
sol2 = "Charge your phone fully and switch it on"
sol3 = "Keep holding the power on button until the screen turns on, if not then contact the phone provider for a replacement."#
sol4 = "You need a screen replacement. Get it fixed"
sol5 = "Get a screen replacement or contact your phone provider for a  replacement."#
sol6 = "You need to update your phone software and apps."
sol7 = "Take the battery out, and put it back in. Then press the power on button until your phone switches on."#
sol8 = "You dont need to do anything. Your phone doesn't have any problems."

if input("Did you  buy your phone recently? ") == 'yes':
if input("Did you drop your phone? ") == 'yes':
    if input("Did it become wet when you dropped it? ") == 'yes':
     print(sol1)
else:  
    if input("Is the phone fully charged? ") == 'yes':
        if input("Is the screen on?") == 'yes':
            print(sol3)
    else:

        print(sol2) 
else:  
    if input("Has your phone ever been too slow? " ) == 'yes':
    print(solution)
    else:  
        if input("Have you got more than 30 apps? ") == 'yes':
        print(sol0)
        else:
            print (sol8)
```

Comment: What you need there is called a [_decision tree_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). Note that a question can appear as multiple times in such a tree but only ever almost once per path from the root to a leaf.

Comment: I have made a decision tree already. Any more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can think of right now, you have two options.

**IF CASES**

You'd just go about defining every path possible. This might be the best option if there are not too many questions.

```
guess = input("Did you drop your phone? ")
if guess == "yes":
    guess2 = input("Did it shatter the screen? ")
    if guess2 == "yes":
        ...
    else:
        ...
else:  # assuming the user entered 'no' if the answer was not 'yes'
    guess2 = input("Did your phone come in contact with water? ")
    if guess2 = "yes":
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Here is a [fully functional example](http://pastebin.com/WR77nV8V) of the if-case method.

**PREDEFINED QUESTION-ID**

You can also give every question a unique ID (e.g. a number), put it in a function and go on from there.

```
def new_question(id):
    if id == 1:
        return question1()
    elif id == 2:
        return question2()
    elif id == 3:
        return question3()
    elif id == 4:
        return question4()
    ... (more ids)

def question1():
    guess = input("Did you drop your phone? ")
    if guess == "yes":
        return 2  # next question will be question 2
    else:
        return 3  # next question will be question 3

def question2():
    guess = input("Did it shatter the screen? ")
    if guess == "yes":
        return 4  # next question will be question 4
    else:
        return 5  # next question will be question 5

def question3():
    guess = input("Did your phone come in contact with water? ")
    if guess == "yes":
        return 4  # next question will be question 4
    else:
        return 7  # next question will be question 7

... (more questions)

answer = 1
while answer != 0:
    answer = new_question(answer)
```

Here is a [fully functional example](http://pastebin.com/NBZUMd0B) of the question-id method

Comment: Thanks you soo much! It helped me a lot!

Comment: @JasonCole No problem! I added a fully functional example of the question-id method, maybe you can use it. Good luck with your project! Would you mind marking the answer as correct and/or upvoting so it can help others too?

Comment: Sure! No problem. And can i put your code on main post for others? Or how do i make it correct?

Comment: Thanks! One thing i don't understand, what are the IDs for and how can i put different solutions instead of "Sorry, no warranty for you" or "your device is still under warranty". Can you explain a bit more? Because i want to put different solutions.